# Journey Builder Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I created a journey, and contacts were evaluated and accepted to enter into the journey. However, it failed to send email. Result says, "

> A subscriber error occered invoiking triggered send. There are no
>   valid subscribers. ErrorCode 180008".

My entry source is Salesforce Data, and I want to send to person account.

Comment: Have you tried any of the following? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000222050&type=1

Comment: I changed "Event DATA" of the Entry event from "First Name" to PersonContact: (First Name) then it completed sending email.

Answer (score 0):

What is the email address you are trying to send to? Marketing Cloud tends block non-personal email addresses such as sales@, marketing@ etc. as it deems it too dangerous to send from the deliverability stand point.

If the email address seems ok, please check whether, in Contact Builder, your journey is using Salesforce Contact ID as a subscriber Key. From the error message, it seems that whatever subscriber key is passed, Marketing Cloud can not quite find an email address for it(or it doesn't accept that email address).